# How to convert date from input to milliseconds

Tags: javascript

So I know that the first thing your going to think is that you have seen a hundred questions just like this but this one is different. I know how to convert Date() to milliseconds but I don't know how to convert a time and date from  See the string from Date looks like this:

```
Tue Jan 14 2020 15:28:10 GMT-0700 (MST)
```

But the string from a date *input* looks like this:

```
2003-01-06T16:56
```

So they're obviously not the same.

So how would I change the date from a date input to milliseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how would I change the date from a date input to milliseconds?

To convert the 2nd string you have there (the input value) to a date, simply pass it into the Date constructor...

```js
var d = new Date("2003-01-06T16:56");
console.log(d.toString());
```

If you want to have a date field in the page where you get the value then give it an ID like this...

```
<input id="dateField" type="date" />
```

and then change the code to...

```
var d = new Date(document.getElementById("dateField").value);
```

Comment: For var d could I just do this?

    var d = new Date(document.querySelector("input[type=date]).value;

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.

Comment: sorry pressed enter instead of shift + enter on accident

Comment: Ok, so what would be the proper syntax?

Comment: I'll add something to the answer.